# Making multiple fetch api calls how to check if all calls have finished?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, promise, ecmascript-6

I am grabbing content from multiple urls. Fetch api uses promises all over.

So my code for one requests looks like this

`fetch(url).then((response)=>response.text()).then(function(html) { //stuff });`

now i have array of urls and multiple calls will be made how do i know if all calls have finished.

i tried using `Promise.all` but if you see there are two promises for every request. Is there a better way, also Promise.all support is not that good either.

Comment: `Promise.all` will work fine here as long as you chain the requests. And anywhere `fetch` is supported, `Promise` will be too.

Comment: ok can you give me example if you have array of urls how would you use promise.all

Comment: `Promise.all(urls.map(url => fetch(url).then(res => res.text()).then(html => (/* stuff */))).then(() => console.log('all urls were fetched and processed'))`

Comment: Thanks @YuryTarabanko if you pose answer ill accept it

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assuming you have an array of urls named `urls`

```
// separate function to make code more clear
const grabContent = url => fetch(url)
     .then(res => res.text())
     .then(html => (/* process html here */))

Promise
    .all(urls.map(grabContent))
    .then(() => console.log(`Urls ${urls} were grabbed`))
```

Comment: You can also just do `Promise.all([url1,url2]).then()` as well

Comment: @clurect - That isn't enough.  `Promise.all()` accepts an array of promises.  It won't do anything useful if you just pass it an array of URLs.

Comment: @clurect `urls` is an array of strings (From OP: now i have array of urls ). Wrapping it with a Promise doesn't make much sense.

Comment: ah yes, my bad. It should've been promises.